# SQL CASE WHEN to narrow results, change field

Tags: sql, case-when

I've read dozens of answers regarding CASE and am not sure that is what i need to be using here, it seems like it should work but its not:

```
Data:
OrderNum    OrderLine  PartNum
200011         1         ABC-1
200011         2         DEF-1
200012         1         XYZ-1

What I would like to return:
OrderNum   Item#
200011     MIXED
200012     XYZ-1


What I am returning instead:
OrderNum   Item#
200011     ABC-1
200011     MIXED
200012     XYZ-1
```

My query:

```
SELECT OrderHed.OrderNum, 
      (CASE WHEN ShipDtl.OrderLine > '1' then 'MIXED' else ShipDtl.PartNum end) as [Item#]
FROM dbo.OrderHed, dbo.ShipDtl
WHERE ShipDtl.Company = OrderHed.Company 
AND ShipDtl.OrderNum = OrderHed.OrderNum
GROUP BY OrderHed.OrderNum, ShipDtl.OrderLine, ShipDtl.Part
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with grouping like

```
SELECT OrderHed.OrderNum, 
      (CASE WHEN SUM(ShipDtl.OrderLine) > 1 then 'MIXED' else MAX(ShipDtl.PartNum) end) as [Item#]
FROM dbo.OrderHed, dbo.ShipDtl
WHERE ShipDtl.Company = OrderHed.Company 
AND ShipDtl.OrderNum = OrderHed.OrderNum
GROUP BY OrderHed.OrderNum
```

SQLFiddle Demo : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/209d8/1

Comment: 1) it should be count(), not sum(). 2) it should be >1, not >'1'

Comment: No, Count() will return 1 if there is only one record for any OrderNum even if it have OrderLine = 2. So it will not update with 'MIXED' for that OrderNum due to count = 1. Btw, I have changed '1' to 1.

Comment: If ShipDtl.OrderLine > 1 then sum() will also be > 1.

Comment: Yes, that is we want to update 'MIXED' text for OrderLine > 1

Comment: Upendra, your solution works perfectly, thank you very much. jva, COUNT seems to be working as well.

Comment: Upendra, your solution works perfectly, thank you! 

The remaining issue I have in practice is when OrderNum >= 2 with OrderLine = 1 in all instances. This can happen because ShipDtl contains more details than what I specified here, for instance, PartNum ships from more than one BinNum. That is more than I asked in the question though, and your answer helped me tremendously, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't write which database engine you use, but if it is SQL 2005 and above, I'd think using the window function for COUNT will make things easier as you then do not need to group.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        OrderHed.OrderNum ,
        CASE 
            WHEN COUNT(ShipDtl.OrderLine) OVER (PARTITION BY ShipDtl.OrderNum) > 1 THEN 'MIXED'
            ELSE PartNum
        END AS [Item#]
FROM    dbo.OrderHed ,
        dbo.ShipDtl
WHERE   ShipDtl.Company = OrderHed.Company
        AND ShipDtl.OrderNum = OrderHed.OrderNum
```

You'll need to DISTINCT though, because it'll select a row per line, but each order with multiple lines will be MIXED, so you can easily distinct.

This will simply select the OrderNum and if multiple orderlines exists per ordernum Count(xxx) OVER (partition by yyy)  it'll select 'MIXED', otherwise the partnum.
And then distinct the result.

Comment: Yes this works, thank you for your answer! I am using SQL2008r2. This solution works for me as well (if I use CASE in front of WHEN). 

Also, if I use GROUP BY at the end I can eliminate the issue I mention in a comment to Upendra, where OrderNum >=2 with some or all  instances having OrderLine = 1. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Missed the case, yes. Have added that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no compulsion to use `CASE` (is there?).

In your example, `CASE` is being used to perform logical `OR`. There are other ways of performing logical `OR` in SQL e.g. `UNION`:

```
WITH T 
     AS
     (
      SELECT OrderHed.OrderNum, ShipDtl.PartNum, ShipDtl.OrderLine
        FROM dbo.OrderHed, dbo.ShipDtl
       WHERE ShipDtl.Company = OrderHed.Company 
             AND ShipDtl.OrderNum = OrderHed.OrderNum
     )
SELECT OrderNum, PartNum
  FROM T
 WHERE OrderLine = 1
       AND OrderNum NOT IN ( 
                            SELECT OrderNum
                              FROM T T2
                             WHERE OrderLine > 1
                           )
UNION
SELECT OrderNum, 'MIXED' AS PartNum
  FROM T
 WHERE OrderLine > 1;
```

Comment: Yes this works as well, thank you for your answer! I have no specific reason to use CASE. Your solution works with no further editing, even when I have more than one OrderLine in ShipDtl with a value of 1.  Thank you for the help.